# Reactjs : TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am new to Reactjs and trying to change the of value text which is entered by user in textbox, after button click event. 
But after button click event I am getting error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined" at handleChange(e) function.Can anyone please help me with whats going wrong here??

Here is the component I am working with :

```
 Constructor(props){
    super();
    this.state={
             typedtext: 'Nothing'
           }
      };

    handleClick(){
              this.handleChange(this.state.typedtext)
             }

    handleChange(e){
            this.setState({ typedtext: e.target.value });  
              }

    render(){

     return(

        <div>
         <label> Typed Value is : {this.state.typedtext} </label> <p> 
         </p>

        <label> Type Something here </label>
          <input type='text'onChange={(e)=>this.handleChange(e)} 
               value=  {this.state.typedtext}/>

       <button onClick={()=>this.handleClick()}> Copy Text </button>
       </div>
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure but ```constructor``` method should start from lower case ```c```

Comment: @DilsMatchanov, I think it's just code copy/paste issue. Also it should be super(props), not super()

Comment: This code works (if change Constructor to constructor).

Comment: @DilsMatchanov yes constructor is starting with lower case only, but still the code is not working its giving the same error when I click on Button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears because when you run `handleChange` in `handleClick` method you use the value of your state as the argument instead of event object. It is trying to get `value` property of string.

Your code should look like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    typedtext: 'Nothing'
  }
};

handleClick(e) {
  this.handleChange(e)
}

handleChange(e) {
  this.setState({
    typedtext: e.target.value
  });
}

render() {

  return (
    <div>
      <label> Typed Value is : {this.state.typedtext} </label> 
      <p></p>

      <label> Type Something here </label>
      <input type='text'onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)} value={this.state.typedtext}/>

      <button onClick={e => this.handleClick(e)}> Copy Text </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But `handleClick` will not copy the text. It will just remove it because `handleChange` will try to get the value of button that doesn't contain any value.

Working code looks like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    typedtext: 'Nothing'
  }
};

handleChange() {
  this.setState({
    typedtext: this.input.value
  });
}

render() {

  return (
    <div>
      <label> Typed Value is : {this.state.typedtext} </label> 
      <p></p>

      <label> Type Something here </label>
      <input type='text'onChange={() => this.handleChange()} value={this.state.typedtext} ref={input => this.input = input}/>

      <button onClick={() => this.handleChange()}> Copy Text </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But you will not be able to see what the button does because while you are typing it already copies the text. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a bind to "**this**" refering this method on contructor:

```js
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
```

The entire code on constructor:

```js
constructor(props){
    super();
    this.state={
        typedtext: 'Nothing'
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
};
```